# How to sort and sum json data by month in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have the following aggregation data coming from my back-end :

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "name": "Cement",
            "year": 2020,
            "month": 6,
            "dayOfMonth": 14
        },
        "totalAmountSold": -6
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "name": "Cement",
            "year": 2020,
            "month": 6,
            "dayOfMonth": 13
        },
        "totalAmountSold": -5
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "name": "Cement",
            "year": 2020,
            "month": 6,
            "dayOfMonth": 16
        },
        "totalAmountSold": -6
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "name": "Pop",
            "year": 2020,
            "month": 6,
            "dayOfMonth": 8
        },
        "totalAmountSold": -11
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "name": "Pop",
            "year": 2020,
            "month": 5,
            "dayOfMonth": 14
        },
        "totalAmountSold": -15
    }
]
```

I want to be able to filter through only data for the previous month (for instance for the month of June, month =5 is filtered ) and sum the 'totalAmountSold' for each entry.

My desired output should read :

```
//Output should be a list of all item(name,month,totalAmountSold forEach item)
{Cement, Month=6 ,totalAmountSold =17},

// assuming Pop had sales in Month=6
{Pop, Month=6 ,totalAmountSold =15},
```

Comment: So what prevents yopu from doing this great job?

Comment: @8SINS - Can you try what I suggested?

Comment: @Ramesh thanks a lot, just saw your suggestion, am trying it out now, I will get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your Objects by month while adding the `totalAmountSold` and then get the values.

```js
const inputArray = [
    {
        "_id": {
            "name": "Cement",
            "year": 2020,
            "month": 6,
            "dayOfMonth": 14
        },
        "totalAmountSold": -6
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "name": "Cement",
            "year": 2020,
            "month": 6,
            "dayOfMonth": 13
        },
        "totalAmountSold": -5
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "name": "Cement",
            "year": 2020,
            "month": 6,
            "dayOfMonth": 16
        },
        "totalAmountSold": -6
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "name": "Pop",
            "year": 2020,
            "month": 6,
            "dayOfMonth": 8
        },
        "totalAmountSold": -11
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "name": "Pop",
            "year": 2020,
            "month": 5,
            "dayOfMonth": 14
        },
        "totalAmountSold": -15
    }
];

const groupedByMonth = Object.values(inputArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(curr._id.month === 6) {
    return (acc[curr._id.name] = { month: curr._id.month, name: curr._id.name,
     totalAmountSold: (acc[curr._id.name]?.totalAmountSold || 0) + curr.totalAmountSold }, acc);
  } 
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(groupedByMonth)
```

Comment: Hi @ramesh, sorry it took a while to respond couldn't help it. Great suggestion, Your snippet was able to sum the "totalAmountSold" for Month=6, but i actually want each item to be summed separately, such that I have "Cement, month=6, totalAmountSold=17" and "Pop, month=6, totalAmountSold=15"   ,  Ihave tried using forEach() but havent made it work yet

Comment: @8SINS - Add the sample output to the question.

Comment: @8SINS - Can you explain your output?

Comment: l want Reduce() to add up all the 'totalAmountSold'  on the 6th month for each item, in this case "Cement , totalAmountSold=17, month=6. and another item will be "Pop , totalAmountSold=17, month=6

Comment: Check my question, I have updated with the desired output....

Comment: @8SINS so you only care about the 6th month?

Comment: am actually interested in always getting the current month.

Comment: However if thats  complicated i can obtain the sum of each item's totalAmountSold field and group per month...and then filter the 6th month. These totalAmountSold  value is actually needed in another query

Comment: @8SINS - Updated my answer. If you want something else then mark this as solved and ask a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216189/discussion-between-8sins-and-ramesh).